# how to decrypt an encrypted password?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

Well I have a problem here in decrypting an encrypted password. 
I have user table in my database with some username and passwords. the passwords are encrypted string and I don't know  what algorithm did the previous developer use to encrypt? 
and I can't access him in at the moment. the project manager also doesn't know and there is no documentation for this project that I can refer to... 
example of one the password 
password: "abc123"
encrypted string: "CSTxWwxwtiE="
can anyone tell me what is the algorithm used to encrypt? 
is there any c# method that can decrypt it?

Comment: If the previous developer did his job properly the passwords have been stored using a one-way hash. You can't decrypt them.

Comment: The presence of `=` at the end may indicate base64 "encryption" but that appears to not be the case here. Without the algorithm, you're doing a Sisyphus.

Comment: do you have the source code of the program? It will help.

Comment: If previous developer was able to read anything than the passwords would be hashed, not encrypted... If you can read - read the source code as suggested by @rcs... Or disassemble IL if you lost the code...

Comment: You don't want/need to decrypt passwords, the password should be unknown to even the developer. If you want to migrate to a new system either use the same hashing method ( by looking in the code ) or send everyone a password reset mail.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for your replies;
After your answer I wrote this code and what I get is not abc123
            var base64 = "CSTxWwxwtiE=";
            var data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
             MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
but this System.byte[];
 plz help me

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the encryption algorithm it is not possible to decrypt the encrypted string. In that case it would be a sort of hacking.

The best guess you can make is that since there is a = sign at the end of your encrypted string hence the developer may have used the base64 encoding. But this too is a guess which you have to verify.

Comment: There's a reason why I surrounded encryption with quotation marks in my comment to the question. It's _not_ encryption, just encoding. Please don't perpetuate the myth :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo:- Got  that. Updated my answer as well! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer;
is there any way to conversion from string to base64 encoding.